# UILabel resizes its SuperView?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have the following view which contains a `UILabel`:

```
class MyView : UIView {

  func viewDidLoad() {

    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth

    bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y + self.imageView!.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - self.imageView!.bounds.size.height))

    // bottomView frame calculation is: (0.0, 355.0, 355.0, 130.0)

    bottomView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    bottomView?.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    bottomView?.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(self.bottomView!)

    var descriptionRect: CGRect = CGRectInset(self.bottomView!.bounds, leftRightInset, 20/2)
    let descriptionLabel = UILabel()
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 3
    descriptionLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    descriptionLabel.font = UIFont(name: MGFont.helvetica, size: 22)
    descriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    descriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    var paragraphStyle:NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
    let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle]
    descriptionLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: previewCard.title, attributes:attributes)
    bottomView?.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

    descriptionLabel.bounds = descriptionRect
    descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
    descriptionLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomView!.bounds.width/2, bottomView!.bounds.height/2 - hotelNameLableHeight/2) 

  }     

}
```

The height of the bottomView should always be fixed.

`MyView` is resized during runtime. This means that the green bottom view also increases in size.

Here is the result when the label has two and three lines:

[image]

It appears that the `UILabel` resizes its super view.

Note that I do not use AutoLayout.

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }
```

**How can I prevent the `UILabel` from resizing its SuperView?**

Edit: I also tried to comment `bottomView?.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Is the label being placed inside a view hierarchy that uses auto layout?

Comment: Have you verified with 4, 5 or more lines of text? Does the height of bottomView keep increasing?

Comment: Post your the `layoutSubviews` of the `self`

Comment: Comment this line and check. bottomView?.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @Bannings I posted layoutSubviews

Comment: @confile How much the executes count of this line: bottomView = UIView(xxx)?

Comment: @Bannings frame: (0.0, 355.0, 355.0, 130.0)

Comment: @confile you haven't answered my question...

Comment: What do you mean by executes count?

Answer (score 0):

Override  `setFrame:` and `setBounds:` of the super view (subclass if they're plain `UIView`s), add breakpoints, and see the stack trace to find out what's causing them to resize.

Comment: Where is setFrame and setBounds?

Comment: @confile you'll have to override these methods

Comment: Which super view are you talking about?

Comment: I use Swift there is no setFrame and setBounds

Comment: I tried this ``class BottomView : UIView {
  
  override func setFrame(frame: CGRect) {
    super.frame = frame
  }
  
}``but it raises errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the autoResizingMask on the label, just set the frame and it will get automatically centered. And of course you can set the insets for the UILabel accordingly.  I've add below testing code FYI:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    addTestView(CGRectMake(0, 200, view.bounds.width, 50), labelStr: "I am a short testing label")
    addTestView(CGRectMake(0, 260, view.bounds.width, 50), labelStr: "I am a very longlonglonglonglonglonglong testing label")
     addTestView(CGRectMake(0, 320, view.bounds.width, 50), labelStr: "I am a very longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong testing label. Will be truncated")
}

func addTestView(frame:CGRect, labelStr: String){
    let bottomView = UIView(frame:frame)
    bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    bottomView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    bottomView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(bottomView)

    var label = UILabel(frame: bottomView.bounds)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = labelStr
    bottomView.addSubview(label)

}
```